# SQL Server - Summing a column based on the first 300 rows (and 301+)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm pulling data from a million+ row table with 25 column headers. I have a simple query that pulls total answered calls and total connected seconds by date.

```
SELECT
convert(date,format(Dateadd(hh,1,[Start Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),103) as [Date]
,sum(iif([type] = 'normal operator call',1,0)) as [answered calls]
,sum([connected (secs)]) as [total con sec]


from inboundcallsview

where [account] = '106844'

and dateadd(hh,1,[start time]) between '2017-05-01' and '2017-06-01'

group by convert(date,format(Dateadd(hh,1,[Start Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),103)
```

What I am looking to do is sum the connected seconds of the first 300 (by the [start time] column) answered calls (any row where [type] = 'normal operator call') of the each day (as defined by the [date] column). As well as the total connected seconds of all calls from 301 onwards. Basically my current output is

[image: current]

and I would like it to be

[image: desired output]

Ignore the change of dates june (06) should be may (05) I messed up creating my example. I'm eventually going to want to do this for all dates so the date parameters don't matter particularly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about the ROW_NUMBER function?

Comment: I know it exists, but not sure how to incorporate it when I'm already splitting and grouping by date and the number of rows per date will be random. That's what I need help with i reckon. IS there some way to make each date it's own subtable and count the rows of that subtable perhaps? What would that look like?

Comment: Look into using `ROW_NUMBER` with `OVER(PARTITION BY (your date output) ORDER BY [Start Time])`   By the way you will have to UNION two derived tables.  One table of 1-300 and another table of 301+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In psuedo code it will look like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT {Your Date Output} AS [date],
         ,[ConnectedSecs]
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY {Your Date Output}, ORDER BY [Start Time]) AS rn
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE {Conditions}
)
SELECT 
  [date],
  'First 300' AS Bracket,
  SUM(ConnectedSecs)
  FROM CTE WHERE rn < 301
  GROUP BY [date]
UNION ALL SELECT 
  [date],
  '301+' AS Bracket,
  SUM(ConnectedSecs)
  FROM CTE WHERE rn >= 301
  GROUP BY [date]
ORDER BY [date],{a case expression to have 'First 300' on top if desired}
```